# Home Name Server

Tags: dns

I would like to set up a name server for my home network so that I can use my easily remembered names to point at my devices. I haven't played with DNS in over 7 years and honestly don't remember how to do this. Can anyone point me to a good "how to" or something of the like to get me started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using dnsmasq, as it will give you a two fold solution: dhcp server and dns proxy for your local network.

You might want to look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq

Advantages of dnsmasq is that it will resolve dhcp names in its dns proxy, and simply use /etc/hosts for static ip you might have. It is much simpler than using a full bind9 server.

Comment: You may already be running dnsmasq by default. If you have a computer you call vince-computer try `ping vince-computer.local`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the network is really simple and static, you could just modify `/etc/hosts` on all devices to have lines like:

```
192.168.1.42  universe
172.17.18.19  foobar
```

If you have too many devices or they change too often, `dnsmasq` (available in the repository) provides you with either a DNS server or a DHCP server, or both. There is a rudimentary setup guide on [community help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq), and documentation on [dnsmasq homepage](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html).

Comment: Thank you. This was more help than I have gotten anywhere.